# How can I window stretch and remove the border graphics for Final Fantasy IX?

Tags: steam, final-fantasy-9

In the Steam version of *Final Fantasy IX*, it seems most resolutions have these strange grey stone like gradient borders and I find them a little off-putting.

Is there a way to remove these and possibly stretch out the game screen in fullscreen?

Comment: Whilst I have not played the steam version - the original game was created for the PSX in the 90s so was never designed for the resolutions offered by a modern monitor - stretching to full screen will more than likely not look great

Comment: @Zoma I accidentally rejected your edit, it appeared to conflict with the authors intent when I checked what was changed, I realized too late that the faulty edit was the previous one and that this one fixes it. I hope you get approved, otherwise feel free to suggest the same edit again, I'm sorry.

Comment: @bearb001 looks like Joachim did the same as you, will suggest it again.

Comment: @Zoma Yes, you're right - I thought the OP wondered how to remove the window stretch, based on the initial wording of the question. Will approve when it shows up :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason there are gray portions on the edges of the screen is because the steam version of the game is a PC port of a mobile port of a PS1 game. The graphics were never intended to be stretched to horizontal resolutions, and as such, the gray bars were used as a solution.

There is no official way to fix this issue. However, according to [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377840/discussions/0/361787186419581146/) on Steam, there is a [tool](https://sfx.thelazy.net/games/preset/4891/) to allow you to stretch the game to your liking - this however may result in worse visuals.

There is also the [Moguri Mod](https://sites.google.com/view/moguri-mod/), which does have the option of using Widescreen displays (while also increasing graphical quality, it uses Ultra HD graphics). It does not fully work, because it doesn't just stretch the game, and as such, hardcoded settings (like some scene transitions and in-game movies) won't be widescreen.